# Maximum number of <iFrame> tags per web page

Tags: html, iframe, browser, web, limit

For a website it is possible to include multiple iFrames for integration of external content. I know that there are other better ways to include such content, but I wonder if there is a browser-specific limit for the number of allowed iFrames on one web page?

Now I thought that there are two possible browser limitation:

1. the number of connection that are needed for including the iFrame resources and
2. the concrete maximum number of allowed  tags.

For (1): I figured that e.g. Mozilla Firefox (v17) has config parameter for maximum number of connections to a server (`network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server`) and an overall limited number of concurrent connections (`network.http.max-connections`). See `about:config`.

For (2) I cannot find any information. Except that there is a higher resource demand and other performance issues there is no fixed limitation for those tags on one page.

Do you have any other information?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to evaluate whether the inclusion of other content via <iFrame> tags is already limited because of browser restrictions and not only because of performance issues

Comment: @KeesSonnema read the question a little better ;)

Comment: I am ware of this, but is there a limit such as 100 iFrames?

Comment: You could place a JavaScript listener in your source. Or build a limiter Plugin that reviews your code with JavaScript and practically does the same. A simple `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').length;` would probably do. If there is overflow, you can let the listener bounce it back, by letting it check your code every so-many milliseconds (100-250~ should probably be fast enough) and let it remove the overflowing `iframe`s again.

Comment: @Allendar: Trial and error is a valid approach but I am looking for a browser vendor limitation (must be documented somewhere)?!

Comment: I mean you could make a Firefox Plugin that keeps listening to your DOM source and check if the amount of `iframes` in your source doesn't exceed a certain amount. If it would, you could use JavaScript to remove all the ones that are too many.

Comment: @chris.tian Just curious, but to what end? Are you trying to batch-limit multiple computers (their browser) in a(n) company/university network? A plugin might not be bad at all for this. The whole idea of a plugin is to extend the functionality of the browser. In the last 16 years I work with HTML/JS, I never heard of such a functionality by default in a browser.

Comment: You want iframe inside iframe? Or parallel iframe?

Comment: @hjpotter92: Parallel iframe

Comment: @Allendar: That might not be appropriate if multiple browsers have to be supported

Comment: @chris.tian So you need to make one for them all, but takes time to do. They won't have it by default. But again; can you explain "why" you want to do it? Maybe there are alternative approaches for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a limit. However, like you've mentioned, your website's speed may decrease with the increase of i-frames.

Here's a great guide for I-Frames: [i frames](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)